# Node js - Reading two CSV files synchronously?

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm having a little trouble reading CSV files. Let me step back. ( I'm using node js, require('csv') )

So I have two CSV files --

1. **us-area-code-cities.csv** - each row or entity contains US area codes and corresponding latitude and longitude values

   201,Bayonne,New Jersey,US,40.66871,-74.11431
2. **sampleData.csv** - contains a timestamp of a call and the telephone number of the caller

   07-JUN-95 11.28.15,1234567890

I have two separate csv objects, one for each CSV file (am not sure about this, please let me know if this is not common):

```
var areaCodeCSV = csv(); 
var phoneDataCSV = csv();
```

First, I need to populate a dictionary to map an area code to a latitude and longitude object using **us-area-code-cities.csv**. Then, when I go through each csv entity in **sampleData.csv**, I want to look up the latitude and longitude value to a caller's area code and convert the area code to a lat/long. But, when I read the **sampleData.csv** file and attempt the look up, it seems that the dictionary has not been populated yet.

Code:

```
areaCodeCSV.from.path('./public/us-area-code-cities.csv').to.array(function (data) {
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    areaCodeDictionary[data[index][0]] = new geoLocation(data[index][4], data[index][5]);
}
console.log(areaCodeDictionary); //prints successfully
});


function convertAreaCodeToGeoObject(areaCode) {return areaCodeDictionary[areaCode]; }

phoneDataCSV.from.path('./public/sampleData.csv').to.array(function 
(data) {
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  var time = data[index][0];
  var ac = convertAreaCodeToGeoObject(data[index][1].substring(0, 3)); //only want the first three digits
  var year = parseInt("20" + time.substring(7, 9));
  var month = convertMonthToNum(time.substring(3, 6));
  var day = parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
  var hours = parseInt(time.substring(10, 12));
  var minutes = parseInt(time.substring(13, 15));
  var seconds = parseInt(time.substring(16));

  console.log("ac:  " + ac); //prints undefined

  phoneData.push(new dataObject(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0), ac));

  console.log(phoneData); //prints {date : undefined,...,date : undefined}
```

Do these CSV files have to be read in synchronously? I'm guessing one is read before the other, so the dictionary is not populated by the time I want to convert the area code to lat/long. Is there an easy workaround here that I am missing? I guess one thing I could do is hard code a dictionary, but if I can get this to work that would be great. It seems so simple! I tried to put one into a function and call that function in the other, but the phoneData array is just empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need insert in the callback function, the proccess of the seconf file:

```
areaCodeCSV.from.path('./public/us-area-code-cities.csv').to.array(function (data) {
    let areaCodeDictionary = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        areaCodeDictionary[data[index][0]] = new geoLocation(data[index][4], data[index][5]);
    }

    proccesSecondFile(areaCodeDictionary);
    console.log(areaCodeDictionary); //prints successfully
});

function proccesSecondFile(areaCodeDictionary) {
    function convertAreaCodeToGeoObject(areaCode) { return areaCodeDictionary[areaCode]; }

    phoneDataCSV.from.path('./public/sampleData.csv').to.array(function(data) {
        for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            var time = data[index][0];
            var ac = convertAreaCodeToGeoObject(data[index][1].substring(0, 3)); //only want the first three digits
            var year = parseInt("20" + time.substring(7, 9));
            var month = convertMonthToNum(time.substring(3, 6));
            var day = parseInt(time.substring(0, 2));
            var hours = parseInt(time.substring(10, 12));
            var minutes = parseInt(time.substring(13, 15));
            var seconds = parseInt(time.substring(16));

            console.log("ac:  " + ac); //prints undefined

            phoneData.push(new dataObject(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0), ac));
        }
        console.log(phoneData); 
        //for websocket
        //var asString = JSON.stringify(phoneData);
        //console.log(asString);
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried that. So I have a couple of issues now. When I print phoneData inside `processSecondFile(areaCodeDictionary)` it prints out the phoneData array multiple times, not a single time. When I print the phoneData array inside the `areaCodeToCSV` function, underneath the callback function `proccesSecondFile(areaCodeDictionary)` the array is empty. Last problem which may not be a problem, but when I connect to my client (using websockets) and print the phoneData array I see [object Object][object Object][object Object]... instead of values.